# Does hardware encryption fail for jailbroken iOS device?

Tags: encryption, ios, jailbreak

I know that iOS has a hardware encryption that it encrypts all your data using your passcode when the screen is locked. However, when I jailbreak my iPhone and ssh to the iOS device, I can browse all the data on my iPhone even my iPhone is screen locked. Does anyone know why? Doesn't this conflict with the iOS's hardware encrytion?

Comment: Are you sure that it encrypts when the screen is locked? I think not. I think that it is stored encrypted when not in use. Installing SSHd on the device unlocks access to the underlying file system. I don't know the actual mechanisms I'm afraid. I would guess that the FS has access to the keys and can unencrypt the data it needs on the fly.

Comment: @JulianKnight Hi, I'm pretty sure that the data are encrypted (at least it is true on in-jail iPhone): (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7011011?start=0&tstart=0). Beside this, the FBI (or NSA?) always say they cannot decrypt data from a screen locked iPhone. Maybe jailbreaking changed some feature of iPhone.

Comment: Sorry, I may a misled slightly. Not all of it can be encrypted since there are background tasks that can be running, those tasks must have some live, unencrypted data. Other than that, everything else wont be in use and therefore will be encrypted. You shouldn't maybe take my word though as I can't claim to be an expert.